# How to check that the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) is correctly working on my pc?

Tags: matlab, centos, matlab-compiler

I tried to install [Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) R2013a v81](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) on my pc using CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511.

Now I would like to know if I installed it properly: **how could I check this?**

Thanks

Comment: As a crazy idea: try it?

Comment: How? What command?

Comment: Why did you install it? What are you supposed to do with it? Try doing whatever you are supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can list the installed versions of mcr with the [`mcrversion`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/ml_code/mcrversion.html) function:

```
[major, minor] = mcrversion
```

If you already managed to compile something into a binary with mcr, just try to run it on your target machine; the application will either work or crash and in that case the system will complain about missing dependencies.

Comment: This is kind of OK, but if you are installing MCR to run MATLAB compiled code without MATLAB, well... you can not call a MATLAB command.